# how seed a table in laravel with relations to itself?

Tags: laravel, migration, relationship, factory, seed

i have this **cows** table migration:

```php
Schema::create('cows', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('name')->nullable(false);
    $table->char('gender',1)->nullable(false);
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('cow_father_id')->nullable();
    $table->foreign('cow_father_id')->references('id')->on('cows')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('cow_mother_id')->nullable();
    $table->foreign('cow_mother_id')->references('id')->on('cows')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

and this in my **Cow** model:

```php
protected $guarded = [];

public function father()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(self::class, 'cow_father_id');
}

public function mother()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(self::class, 'cow_mother_id');
}

public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'cow_father_id')->orWhere('cow_mother_id', $this->id);
}
```

**what would be the factory and database seeder for this table, taking into consideration its relationship with itself?**

ensuring that the gender of the mothers is female **F** and the gender of the fathers is male **M**.

what I have achieved on my own does not meet my needs, this is my **CowFactory**.

```php
use App\Cow;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

Cow::create([
    'name' => 'adam',
    'gender' => 'M'
]);

Cow::create([
    'name' => 'eve',
    'gender' => 'F'
]);

$factory->define(Cow::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'gender' =>  $faker->randomElement(['M', 'F']),
        'cow_father_id' => Cow::where('gender','M')->get()->random()->id,//Cow::all()->random()->id,
        'cow_mother_id' => Cow::where('gender','F')->get()->random()->id,//Cow::all()->random()->id,
    ];
});
```

as you can see, I have generated an adam and an eve without father or mother.

and this is what is in my **DatabaseSeeder**.

```php
public function run()
    {
        factory(Cow::class, 20)->create()->each(function($c) {
            dump($c->father()->first()->name.','.$c->mother()->first()->name);
            //$c->mother()->save(factory(Cow::class)->make());
            //$c->father()->save(factory(Cow::class)->make());
        });
    }
```

I can print the name of the assigned father and mother, but I can not achieve that in an automatic way the cows that are generated can be fathers or mothers of the other cows, I can only achieve that all of them have the same parents.

I want a **DatabaseSeed** that generates these cows with different fathers and mothers. that can be repeated (several cows with the same father and mother, but not all) and even that these can be null.

but if I load an id of father or mother that this if it exists in my DB.

Comment: You should be able to use seeders and factories just like with a regular relationship. Do you have a specific question?

Comment: apparently not, what I want is know how I can automatically generate x cows and as they are generated these can be fathers or mothers of the cows that are generated after them distinguishing by gender.

Comment: Only cows with female gender **F** are allowed to be mothers, and vice versa with fathers (**M**)

Comment: (I don't want the same father and mother for everyone, but I allow them be repeated)

Comment: I have updated the question so that my problem can be better understood.